# how to use walk method to join two tables in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, collection

friends,
how to use the walk() method to join two tables in Magento 2
I have 2 tables and I want to join them based on some conditioning.
my present code looks like this

```
    $result = array();
    $model = $this->certificationModel->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('SKU', array('eq' => $sku));
    foreach ($model->getData() as $key => $value) {
        $isActive = $this->certificateModel->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('title', array('eq' => $value['Certification']))
            ->addFieldToSelect('status')->getData();
        $certificateId = $this->certificateModel->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('title', array('eq' => $value['Certification']))
            ->addFieldToSelect('id')->getData();
        if ($isActive[0]['status'] == 1) {
            $result[] = $this->certificateModel->create()->load($certificateId[0]['id'])->getData();
        }
    }
    return $result;
```

how I can implement **walk()** here
i an using [this](http://www.matheusgontijo.com/2018/02/10/magento-2-working-with-large-collections-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-xxxx-bytes-exhausted/) referance

**thanks for help**